# How to fix the display issues with Pretty-Printing of symbolic math in Ipython dark background?

Tags: console, ipython, spyder, pretty-print

I am using Spyder with Ipython console in dark mode. It is really hard to read the pretty-print of symbolic math in the console. This is how it looks like in light mode.

[image]

And this is how it looks like in the dark mode.

[image]

Is there any fix to this problem?

I know, while asking questions we should use minimal images. But the question is related to the display issue, so I thought it's better to add images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this [Github issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3798). The issue was resolved with this [pull request](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-kernels/pull/137)

All we need to do is, go to Preferences-> IPython Console-> Advanced settings-> check use symbolic math.

If you want to set a custom forecolor for the SymPy, use this command in the IPython console

```
ip.kernel.set_sympy_forecolor(background_color='dark')
```

And it looks pretty cool now.

[image]